# window.location.hash not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I have a link (`index.html#services`) and a `<div id="services>` that I'm trying to change the background color of when the link is clicked and then fade back. I'm using the latest jQuery and [jQuery Color](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/jquery.color.js) plugin, and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash === '#services') {
        var service = $('#services');
        var originalColor = service.css('background-color');

        service.css('background-color', '#FFEE9F').animate({
            'background-color': originalColor
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

to do the highlighting, but it's not working. Anyone know why?

Comment: You also miss closing quote for your div id.

Comment: Opps, that's not in my actual code just a typo here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is only run when the page is loaded, not when a link with a hash is clicked. Try following the link (`index.html#services`) directly from a new browser tab and it will probably work. What you need to do is run that code when the hash is changed. New browsers have an `onhashchange` event - but no such thing on older browsers. For old browsers you could poll the hash property every so often to see if it has changed.

If by chance you have a specific identifier (css class, id, name, etc.) on the links that trigger that animation, you could add a `click` listener to run that code. For example:

```
function animateBackground() {
    var service = $('#services');
    var originalColor = service.css('background-color');

    service.css('background-color', '#FFEE9F').animate({
        'background-color': originalColor
    }, 3000);
}

$(function () { // shortcut to $(document.ready)
   $('.fade-bg').live('click', animateBackground);
   animateBackground();
});
```

Comment: Ah you were right, I tried refreshing the page from that link before... but it actually took opening a new tab and copy/pasting it. Thanks! How could I make it work whenever the link is clicked (it's part of my navigation.)

Comment: Opps, replied before seeing your edited answer. Could you show me how that would be done? I'm new to JS, or would that be too much to ask?

Comment: Again... you beat me to my response ha. So if I were to, per say, do `<a href="index.html#services" id="listen">Link</a>` the above code would work?

Comment: @Matt: If you just wanted to copy and paste that JS code, your link would look like: `<a href="index.html#services" id="listen" class='fade-bg'>Link</a>`. Or, if you want it to work with the anchor you just pasted in that comment, you would change `$('.fade-bg')` to `$('#listen')`. Also, needless to say the code would go inside the ready function.

Comment: It works, tyvm. I'm going to try and understand it better now :).

Comment: I found a bug. It works when you're *on* `index.html`, but on any other page it doesn't. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Never mind! I just added what I had before as a script too. I'm sure that's a bad way (and overly redundant), but it works. Now when a click is made, it works, and when the page is first loaded (from another page) it works too :).

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, I should have mentioned that the other code needs to stay there. What you could do to reduce redundancy is put all that code in a function, and then run that function in the ready event, and assign that function for the click handler as well. I'll edit it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or use

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    if(window.location.hash === '#services') {
        var service = $('#services');
        var originalColor = service.css('background-color');

        service.css('background-color', '#FFEE9F').animate({
            'background-color': originalColor
        }, 3000);
    }
};
```

depending on which browsers you target.